# Two FKs in Entity Framework Fluent API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I'm struggling connecting two really simple tables:

```
[Table("Item")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [Column("itemId", TypeName = "int")]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}

[Table("LinkedItems")]
public class LinkedItem
{
    [Key]
    [Column("itemId", TypeName = "int")]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Column("parentItemId", TypeName = "int")]
    public int ParentItemId { get; set; }
}
```

There are two Foreign Keys in `LinkedItem` table:

1. `itemId`, points to the table `Item` to show itself
2. `parentItemId`, points to the table `Item`  to show its parent

I would like to accomplish something like this:

```
[Table("Item")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [Column("itemId", TypeName = "int")]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<LinkedItem> ChildItems { get; set; }
    public LinkedItem LinkedItem { get; set; }
}

[Table("LinkedItems")]
public class LinkedItem
{
    [Key]
    [Column("itemId", TypeName = "int")]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Column("parentItemId", TypeName = "int")]
    public int ParentItemId { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public Item ParentItem { get; set; }
}
```

I was successful with creating connection from Item to LinkedItem:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasOptional(i => i.LinkedItem).WithRequired(i => i.Item);
```

but I can't add another connection. Can you help me with Fluent API configuration for these two tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A LinkedItem class isn't necessary for this. You can simply accomplish this with one class.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual Item ParentItem { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> ChildItems { get; set; }
}

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasRequired(entity => entity.ParentItem)
            .WithMany(entity => entity.ChildItems)
            .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.ParentItemId);
```

Otherwise simply add:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
    .HasMany(entity => entity.ChildItems)
    .WithRequired(entity => entity.ParentItem)
    .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.ParentItemId);
```

EDIT: extended answer.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
        .HasOptional(entity => entity.LinkedItem)
        .WithRequired(entity => entity.Item);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
        .HasMany(entity => entity.ChildItems)
        .WithRequired(entity => entity.ParentItem)
        .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.ParentItemId);
}

[Table("Item")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LinkedItem> ChildItems { get; set; }

    public virtual LinkedItem LinkedItem { get; set; }
}

[Table("LinkedItem")]
public class LinkedItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public int ParentItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    public virtual Item ParentItem { get; set; }
}
```

This gets me the results with the test tables I set up:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the connection is in LinkedItem. The database already exist and I'm not the author :/

Comment: I don't understand. You don't mention LinkedItem once, and it is the only place where `Item` can find its parent or kids. Imagine Item table in the database is only a list of integers, nothing more. The connection is done in LinkedItem class.  Can you explain?

Comment: @Marshall The LinkedItem class is mentioned through the relationship. Much like you mentioned it in your code "modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasOptional(i => i.LinkedItem).WithRequired(i => i.Item);" i.Item points to LinkedItem.Item here. There is no need to configure the other end of the relationship (LinkedItem) because you have already mentioned it here. It doesn't matter where you start. You could just as easily have said "modelBuilder.Entity<LinkedItem>().HasRequired(i => i.Item).WithOptional(i => i.LinkedItem);".

Comment: Thanks bdebaere, but can you post both classes, with complete fluent API? It doesn't look like it's working for me:/

Comment: @Marshall I have edited my answer. Please provide more information, like an error, if it still isn't working.

Comment: Thanks again, but why those members are virtual?Is it necessary?

Comment: @Marshall In short: the virtual keyword is used by EF to mark them for lazy loading, the process in which the related entity is only being loaded on demand.

Comment: Alright! I think I got it now. So I don't have to make them "virtual". I can always use "Include" explicitly, right ?

Comment: @Marshall Yes, that is true.